# Adding div with different text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made myself a list adder.  When you click the link, it adds a div.  I am trying to add the current text of the input into the innertext of the div, then append it.  After it is added, i want the text to clear in the input.  I have tried this http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/hwbcs/2/ but I am stuck, and have no idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is, you're getting the value of `txt` only when the page loads, so the variable will always contain an empty value.

The second problem is, you're actually trying to write `txt` to `this.innerText`. That's a double mistake, because `this` in that context is the link clicked, and jQuery has no `.innerText` (there's `.text` and `.html`).

Last, to clear the input, just use `$('input').val('');`. Passing an empty string to `.val()` sets the input text to that string.

Here's a [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/hwbcs/4/).

Comment: is there a way you can center the text horizontally and the arrows a little right, like i had it....thanks for the answer

Comment: the X's do not stay in the same place, they move with how long the text is...is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Hey, how do i keep the X's from moving left due to the length of the div's text?

Comment: I guess you should write a separate question about this.